# Routes in react not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've used routes to update props in my same component,
but on clicking the buttons only links change in the url but no routing happens in the webpage, after reloading it works fine.

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import News from './components/News';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Navbar/>
        <Router>
          <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<News key={"1"} country={"in"}  category="general" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/general" element={<News key={"2"} country={"in"} category="general" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/business" element={<News key={"3"} country={"in"} category="business" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/entertainment" element={<News key={"4"} country={"in"} category="entertainment" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/health" element={<News key="health" country={"in"} category="health" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/science" element={<News key="science" country={"in"} category="science" pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" country={"in"} category={"sports"} pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/technology" element={<News key="technology" country={"in"} category={"technology"} pageSize={6}/>}  />
            <Route exact path="/education" element={<News key="education" country={"in"} category={"education"} pageSize={6}/>}  />
          </Routes>  
        </Router>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

News.js:

```
import Loading from './Loading';
import NewsItem from './NewsItem'
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class News extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        articles: [],
        loading: false,
        page: 1,
        totalResults: 0
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    var url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=71af8e98db3b4e04b13dcfaca6f9ee2a&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    var data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      totalResults: parsedData.totalResults,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  handleNext = async () => {
    console.log("next");
    console.log(this.state.totalResults, this.state.page);
    if ((this.state.page + 1) > Math.ceil(this.state.totalResults / 6)){

    } else {
      var url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=71af8e98db3b4e04b13dcfaca6f9ee2a&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
      this.setState({ loading: true });
      var data = await fetch(url);
      let parsedData = await data.json();
      console.log(parsedData);
      this.setState({
        articles: parsedData.articles,
        page: this.state.page + 1,
        loading: false
      });
    }
  }

  handlePrev = async () => {
    console.log("previous");
      
    var url = `https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=${this.props.country}&category=${this.props.category}&apiKey=71af8e98db3b4e04b13dcfaca6f9ee2a&page=${this.state.page + 1}&pageSize=${this.props.pageSize}`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    var data = await fetch(url);
    let parsedData = await data.json();
    
    console.log(parsedData);
    this.setState({
      articles: parsedData.articles,
      page: this.state.page - 1,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div className="container my-3">
          <h1 className='text-center my-5'>Top News Headlines :</h1>
          {this.state.loading && <Loading/>}
          <div className="row my-3">
            {!this.state.loading && this.state.articles.map((element) => {
              return <div className="col" key={element.url}>
                <NewsItem imageurl={element.urlToImage} title={element.title} description={element.description} author={element.author} time={element.publishedAt} />
              </div>
            })}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="container d-flex justify-content-around my-5">
          <button disabled={this.state.page<=1} type="button" onClick={this.handlePrev} className="btn btn-primary">&larr;Previous </button>
          <button disabled={(this.state.page + 1) > Math.ceil(this.state.totalResults/6)} type="button" onClick={this.handleNext} className="btn btn-primary">Next &rarr;</button>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
            <div className="container-fluid ">
              <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">News Letter</Link>
              <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/general" className="nav-link" >Home</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/business" className="nav-link">Business</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/entertainment" className="nav-link">Entertainment</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/health" className="nav-link">Health</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/science" className="nav-link">Science</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/sports" className="nav-link">Sports</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/technology" className="nav-link">Technology</Link></li>
                  <li className="nav-item"> <Link to="/education" className="nav-link">Education</Link></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

I tried routing and update page content but only url changed.

Comment: Why is your IF statement empty?

Comment: How are you navigating between the pages? Should look something like const navigate = useNavigate()
navigate('/education')

Comment: In case you haven't taken the full [tour] yet (*you earn a badge BTW*) or just missed it, there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 0):

We have some usage order issues.
Correct usage:

```js
// App.js
<BrowserRouter>
   <Navbar />
   <Pages />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Remove 'BrowserRouter' from your Navbar.js and up it to App.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You are rendering different parts of your UI into ***different*** routers. Routers don't share any state or information. What happens in one router, e.g. clicking a link, isn't made available to any other router the app may be rendering.

You need only one router per app to provide the same single routing context to all routes, links, hooks, etc. Remove the `BrowserRouter` from `Navbar` and promote the `BrowserRouter` in `App` to wrap around both the `Navbar` and the `Routes`.

Example:

Navbar

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default class Navbar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="dark">
        <div className="container-fluid ">
          <Link className="navbar-brand" to="/">News Letter</Link>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/general" className="nav-link" >Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/business" className="nav-link">Business</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/entertainment" className="nav-link">Entertainment</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/health" className="nav-link">Health</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/science" className="nav-link">Science</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/sports" className="nav-link">Sports</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/technology" className="nav-link">Technology</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item">
                <Link to="/education" className="nav-link">Education</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
    );
  };
}
```

App

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<News key={"1"} country="in"  category="general" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/general" element={<News key={"2"} country="in" category="general" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/business" element={<News key={"3"} country="in" category="business" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/entertainment" element={<News key={"4"} country="in" category="entertainment" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/health" element={<News key="health" country="in" category="health" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/science" element={<News key="science" country="in" category="science" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/sports" element={<News key="sports" country="in" category="sports" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/technology" element={<News key="technology" country="in" category="technology" pageSize={6} />} />
          <Route path="/education" element={<News key="education" country="in" category="education" pageSize={6} />} />
        </Routes>  
      </Router>
    );
  };
}
```

Comment: @LakshyaSharma Welcome, glad to help. Cheers and good luck!